# C++ - Textbox with new lines

Tags: c++

```
textBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("RICHEDIT"), 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | WS_BORDER, 12, 12, 393, 332, HWND, (HMENU)mainTextBox, NULL, NULL);
```

is my current code, and when I press enter on the textbox it *does not* create a new line, and i'm trying to do that.

so to explain this further, this textbox that I made works, but when you press enter, it doesn't create a new line like I want it to.

I tried so when you press enter, it prints '\r\n' to the textbox, but that's really weird and hard to control. Any help?

Comment: Which library are you using? Please answer to this question by adding the tag to your question.

Comment: Where do you make this call ? What is HWND in the call ?

Comment: use `WS_WANTRETURN` in your edit style if your text box is in a dialog box, otherwise hitting the enter key will default to clicking the dialogs default button (such as the OK button).